# ODATA and $getJSON - SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

Tags: cors, odata, getjson

I am consuming an ODATA service which is under development and I am running it locally. It is getting consumed from jQuery using the below code. The JavaScript is rendered from an Nintex Form hosted in the SharePoint environment in a different domain.

Browser used for testing is 'FireFox'

```
    var url = "http://localhost:57368/odata/EmployeesLeaves('340674')";

    $.getJSON(url + "?callback=?", function (data) {
       alert('Coming...');
    });
```

I can see the JSON object in the FireBug/FireFox, but also get the error in the Console **'SyntaxError: missing ; before statement "odata.metadata":"http://localhost:57368/odata/$metadata#EmployeesLeaves/@El'**

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Thanks

Neeraj Matta

Comment: JSON or JSONP? "?callback=?",

Comment: Since the URL has a "callback" its JSONP.

Comment: why get JSONP error, but you want to get is a JSON, can you set data type to json?

Comment: I am doing a Cross Domain call, so for me JSONP is the only option.

Answer (score 0):

The WEBAPI service what was been accessed, CORS was not enabled on it.

Below link would help enabling CORS on the Web Service.

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api